# Mixing tikz nodes and tabular

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I'm trying to get a node to fit all the cells in a table inside a tabular environment, but it seems tikz can only work inside the current cell in my document and in the minimal example it showed something even weirder covering half the table, then when I compiled it again it went back to working only inside the last cell. Kind of confused here. The following document shows more or less what I would want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, calc, fit}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Anatomía de la representación tabular}
    \def\arraystretch{2}\tabcolsep=10pt
    \begin{table}
    \caption {Título de la tabla}
    \begin{tabular}{c|ccc}
        \multirow{2}{1.5cm}{Columna Princpial} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Columna 2} & \multirow{2}{2cm}{Columna 3} \\[0.5\baselineskip]
        & Sub 1 & Sub 2 & \\
        \hline
        Categoría 1 & \tikz{ \node[remember picture, anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, draw] (celda1) {Celda}; } & Celda & Celda \\
        Categoría 2 & Celda & Celda & \tikz{ \node[remember picture, anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, draw] (celda2) {Celda}; }
        \tikz{
            \node [remember picture, draw = red, fit = (celda1) (celda2), overlay] {};
        }
    \end{tabular}
    \\[0.5\baselineskip]
    Origen de la tabla \\
    Notas al pie 
    \end{table}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `TiKZ` needs to `remember` is the whole picture and not only some `nodes`. `remember picture` option must be applied to `\tikz` command or `tikzpicture` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, calc, fit}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Anatomía de la representación tabular}
    \def\arraystretch{2}\tabcolsep=10pt
    \begin{table}
    \caption {Título de la tabla}
    \begin{tabular}{c|ccc}
        \multirow{2}{1.5cm}{Columna Princpial} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Columna 2} & \multirow{2}{2cm}{Columna 3} \\[0.5\baselineskip]
        & Sub 1 & Sub 2 & \\
        \hline
        Categoría 1 & \tikz[remember picture]{ \node[anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, draw] (celda1) {Celda}; } & Celda & Celda \\
        Categoría 2 & Celda & Celda & \tikz[remember picture]{ \node[anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, draw] (celda2) {Celda}; }
        \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
            \node [draw = red, fit = (celda1) (celda2)] {};
        }
    \end{tabular}
    \\[0.5\baselineskip]
    Origen de la tabla \\
    Notas al pie 
    \end{table}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]